# Автоматическое упорядочивание по алфавиту

Tags: c#, .net, сортировка

Существует ли инструмент, позволяющий автоматически упорядочить по алфавиту параметры функций, сами функции и свойства в классах сразу по всему проекту, написанному на C#?

Comment: ReSharper поможет, ссылочка [тут](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: [встроенными средствами вы можете поменять порядок параметров](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.csharp.refactoring.reorder);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Упорядочение по алфавиту -- сомнительная идея. И вот почему:

- Параметры в методах располагают обычно по важности или по смыслу (например, копируем из одного места в другое: метод `Copy(source, destination)`, а не `Copy(destination, source)`)
- Свойства и методы располагают обычно а) блоками (например, поля, конструктор, свойства, методы) и б) от публичных к приватным (чтобы контракт находился "выше" в файле с исходником и не приходилось скроллить по всему файлу)

---

Исходную задачу можно решить, [перенастроив Решарпер](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1521242/1985167), или воспользовавшись [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com). Решарпер по идее позволит сделать сортировку по всему проекту, насчет MZ-Tools надо смотреть.

Альтернативный вариант решения -- написать свою тулу, используя Roslyn.

Comment: +1. В книге "Совершенный код" довольно подробно написаны рекомендации к оформлению кода (в том числе именно про параметры функции тоже есть) с обоснованием. Очень советую почитать (а лучше ПРОчитать) книгу

Comment: + полезно использовать #region description <code> #endregion для группировки членов класса и более комфортного просмотра кода, если класс большой. В VS во всяком случае, за остальные IDE не поручусь

Comment: @rdorn к сожалению, регионами очень часто маскируют тот факт, что код неприлично раздулся и требует рефакторинга. Будь то количество кода в самом классе (следует ли он SRP?), или слишком большой содержимое ветки `if { ... }` (как минимум extract method, как максимум -- проверка на SRP). Но в принципе ничего плохого в них нет, если они используются с умом.

Comment: Без ума и от манны небесной бед не оберешься =)

Comment: @rdorn точно :).

Comment: Спасибо, как правильно я знаю. Мне интересно сталкивался ли кто с подобной задачей или нет и есть ли автоматические средства для ее решения.

Comment: @Сергей обновил ответ.

Comment: @andreycha Большое спасибо, попробую с Resharper-ом разобраться